# Unable to retrieve the value of <h:selectBooleanCheckbox> inside my managed bean's action method

Tags: jsf

JSF view code:

```
<f:view>
    <h:form>
        <h:panelGrid>
            <h:inputText id="key" value="#{myManagedBean.key}"/>
            <h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="rerun" value="#{myManagedBean.rerun}" rendered="#{myManagedBean.displayRerun}"/>
            <h:commandButton id="check" action="#{myManagedBean.check}"/>
        </h:panelGrid>
    </h:form>
<f:view>
```

JSF model code:

```
public class MyManagedBean {

    private boolean displayRerun;


    public void setDisplayRerun(boolean aDisplayRerun) {
       this.displayRerun = aDisplayRerun        }

    public boolean getDisplayRerun() {
       return this.displayRerun;
    }

   private String key;


    public void setKey(String aKey) {
       this.key = aKey
    }

    public String getKey() {
       return this.key;
    }
    private boolean rerun;


    public void setRerun(boolean arerun) {
       this.rerun = arerun
    }

    public boolean getRerun() {
       return this.rerun;
    }

    public String check() {
        //do data validation
        setDisplayRerun(true);
        System.out.println(getRerun());
    }

}
```

This always prints `false` regardless of whether the checkbox is checked or not.

> Additional Information on my requirement:

Nick/BalusC, my managed bean is of request scope. It is indeed simplified code snippet that I presented. My page has couple of user input controls along with a command button. On submit of command button, I call action method of backing bean, in which I do data validation (in this case I lookup database and see if the inputs are already registered.) If already registered, I come back to  the same page, this is when I display the singleBooleanCheckBox for the user to select and hit the command button again. 
I am toggling the display of the checkbox based on a managedbean property (a boolean flag set during data validation).

When I re-submit the page with checkbox checked, I do not receive this data.

For further verification, I replace the selectBooleanCheckbox, with a command button with similar behavior (basically do not render it initially, but only show it on data validation). I mapped its @action to my managedbean's action method. To my surprise, when I hit the button, the action method is not executed. Instead, the page is refreshed like in a "immediate" scenario or a redirect.

I have been struggling on this for almost 6 hrs. Appreciate your experienced insights.

Thanks.

Comment: What is the scope of the managed bean?

Comment: The code which you've posted as far is perfectly fine. The problem lies somewhere else. Likely you've oversimplified the code snippet. Please post a fullworthy [SSCCE](http://sscce.org). First guess: you're using this in a datatable and the model is not properly been preserved. @Nick: can you give an example how the scope could matter in this particular problem?

Comment: Nick/BalusC, my managed bean is request scope. Some additional updates on the things I tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you've actually a `rendered` attribute on the checkbox (that was not present in your initial question) and the bean is request scoped (it would have worked when it was session scoped). The submitted checkbox value will not be gathered during apply request values phase when this attribtue evaluates `false` at that point.

You basically need to retain the condition responsible for the rendered attribute in the subsequent request as well. This can be done in several ways: putting bean in session scope, using Tomahawk's `t:saveState` or `h:inputHidden` with a bean `binding`. Each is outlined in detail in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1925118/values-lost-after-validation-error-in-jsf/1925318#1925318).

Comment: Balusc, Thanks for the quick response. Appreciate the link you have provided. As I read your comment, 3 options were specified. I am using tomahawk. My understanding from the read is I need to add <t:saveState/> which should do the trick. do I still need to have the hidden field as well?

Comment: No, just placing `<t:saveState value="#{myManagedBean.displayRerun}" />` somewhere in the view ought to do it.

Comment: A Big Thank You. Yes it worked. Appreciate all the help you do.

Comment: BaluSc, I am running into another problem with this approach. With the <t:saveState>, i could submit the formdata to action method when I hit the newly displayed button.(For more userfriendly ness, I changed my design to used a command button insteadof checkbox). All is fine. But when I hit the refresh page or the menu link that displays the original page, I still get the "DisplayReRun" button displayed. Currently, I am toggling the displayReRun flag in my action method. But the above case is when, the action is not executed. What are my other options to reset the flag? Thanks!!

Comment: Disable browser caching of the JSF pages using a `Filter`. You can find an example in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3728875/jsf-weird-behavior-when-clear-inputtextarea-with-ajax/3729341#3729341).

Comment: @BaluSc, Apologies for getting back late on this. All my pages has a include which has necessary cache clearing mechanisms as you have suggested with the Filter option. To briefly showcase my application flow, I have a left-nav menu where in a link will load my form page. On create click, I execute a bean method where in I am toggling the hidden field. As suggested previously, <t:saveState> is perfectly re-submitting my form data on create btn submit. However, the issue is when I click on my leftNav link (with out create btn action). My form page loads, but the hidden flag is not reset.

Comment: @BaluSc, I have fixed the issue alternatively. Basically, I split my form page into couple of includes, so that I make sure that the component tree rendered on the page is refreshed. Thanks.